# What is the breakdown of performance enhancement for vectorized UDFs?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm looking at the vectorized UDFs in Spark 2.3.  In this [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Til-StSDvfA), it talks about (at least) two issues.

- Slow Serialization
- Inefficient data structures in python

I completely understand the benefit of letting a data scientist work with the frameworks they are used to, and I see from a performance perspective in [this link](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html), this feature has a large benefit.  Does anyone have any data on how much of this is due to serialization improvement and how much is due to pandas?

Comment: Why don't you measure it yourself? The only `pandas_udf` variant which is comparable to `udf` is `SCALAR`. Prepare identity (i.e. `lambda x: x`) for each supported type for both `pandas_udf` and `udf` an compare performance. This will be as close to isolating serde component as you can really get. As of Pandas component there is really no meaningful answer - as both `pandas_udf` and `udf` can be implemented in a number of ways, which don't have obvious equivalents on both sides.

Comment: Hi @user10938362, I didn't measure it myself because I don't think its trivial to do so.  I'm not sure measuring `lambda x: x` would answer my question.  I could measure that one case but does would the serialization benefit be the same for a boolean as it would an int, a double, a string, etc.  Would it matter if the VMs had to then do a cdf vs a simple `x+1` as in the examples presented?  I am asking the community to see if someone will share some knowledge I don't have

Comment: _for each supported type_... :) As of specific operation - you cannot really meaningfully compare anything beyond simple scalar-like operations. To do something like cdf, with `udf` you'd need something like `collect_list`, which introduces huge overhead unrelated to serialization or operation itself, and fundamentally affects overall process. At the same time question Pandas vs. some-other-implementation can be easily answered outside Spark - with `list` of 100 inputs (that's hardcoded in Spark source) on one side, and comparable Pandas object on the other.

Comment: I think I shouldn't responded with specifics, but I did miss the `for each supported type` ;-).  Point is, yes for any question posed on stack overflow one could spend time and probably eventually answer it.  I'm asking if someone has the answer to the question.